# Remove assembly from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am creating web applications, in which I have 2 applications working as parent and child,

So in my `IIS` I created a `website` for `application1` and added `application2` inside `application1` in `IIS` but the problem is, I have a `reference` for `dotnetcharge.dll` in my Parent Project but when I run Child project from IIS I am getting the reference error for `dotnetcharge.dll`

[image]

so I added the dll reference in project2's bin folder but still getting same error,

so I decided to remove the assembly reference from child web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
    <assemblies>
        <remove assembly="dotnetcharge"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

but nothing worked here,

how can I remove reference for the children application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have removed your `assemblies` properly,

the problem might be when you are uploading you application on `IIS` the route for web.config can be other then what you think,

I think so the path of web.config is creating problem, try to change the route while uploading on web.config